# Pine Script v4 - How do I set a stop loss at a previous bar's high/low?

Tags: pine-script

Please help,

```
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when = bullish, comment = "Entered Long")
// Stop loss at previous bar's low
// Take profit at 1.5x the risk

strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, when = bearish, comment = "Entered Short")
// Stop loss at previous bar's high
// Take profit at 1.5x the risk
```

I was thinking of something like, for long entries, `loss = abs(strategy.position_avg_price - low[1]) / syminfo.mintick`, but `low[1]`'s value obviously changes every bar. Plus, I couldn't even cast it right, `Unknown argument 'loss' of type 'series[float]'` So, pretty much, how do I access a previous bar's high/low value and assign it to variable in a way that it remains static for the duration of the strategy?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can assign variable to remain static using the valuewhen function, i use similar code below,

L= valuewhen(EL,lowest(low,3),0)

L will remain constant during excution.